# Using `recoverPersonalSignature` from `eth-sig-util` to verify message signed with go-ethereum's `crypto` package

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, cryptography

I am using https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto#Sign to sign an arbitrary message and trying to recover the signer address using `sigUtil.recoverPersonalSignature`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-sig-util#recoverpersonalsignature-msgparams). This doesn't return the correct address.

Example - Signing a message:

```
msg := "testmsg"
msgHash := crypto.Keccak256Hash([]byte(msg))
sigBytes, err := crypto.Sign(msgHash.Bytes(), privKey)
if err != nil {
        // handle error
}
sig := hexutil.Encode(sigBytes)
```

Signature recovery using https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-sig-util#recoverpersonalsignature-msgparams, where `ctx.request.body.msg` and `ctx.request.body.sig` are the message and signatures respectively obtained from a http request body:

```
address = sigUtil.recoverPersonalSignature({data: ctx.request.body.msg, sig: ctx.request.body.sig});
```

What am I missing here? What might be the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

From https://yos.io/2018/11/16/ethereum-signatures/:

> The eth_sign method calculates an Ethereum specific signature with:
>
> `eth_sign(keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + len(message) +
>   message))).`
>
> The prefix to the message makes the calculated signature recognisable
>   as an Ethereum specific signature.

The above problem can therefore be solved as follows:

```
msg := "testmsg"
prefixedMsg := fmt.Sprintf("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n%d%s", len(msg), msg)
msgHash := crypto.Keccak256Hash([]byte(prefixedMsg))
sigBytes, err := crypto.Sign(msgHash.Bytes(), privKey)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
// optional: add 27 to the 65th byte
sigBytes[64] = uint8(int(sigBytes[64])) + 27
sig := hexutil.Encode(sigBytes)
```

The message signer can be correctly recovered using this signature. Note how I added 27 to the 65th byte of the signature. This gives me the exact Ethereum signature (v = 27 or 28) for address recovery.